# Error: Network error on Axios API call

Tags: reactjs, api, request, axios, general-network-error

I am working with the CryptoCompare API to get data about cryptocurrencies for my project. I've made a few requests to the API and have had no issue getting a response.

Some of the queries for the API look like this:
**https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR**

And others look like this:
**https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD**

When I make requests to URLs that look like the first I am able to get a response from the API and retrieve the data. When I make the same request but for one of the URLs that look like the second I get an error. **Error: Network error** is all it says.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";


class CoinInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      coinInfo: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD`)
    .then(res => {
      const info = res.data;
      this.setState({ coinInfo: info});
      console.log(info);
    });
  }



  render() {

    return (
      <div className="container">

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CoinInfo;
```

If I swap out the URL in the Axios request and replace it with the other API endpoint/URL it works perfectly fine. It also works fine with any of the other CryptoCompare endpoints that have the root "min-api.cryptocompare.com".

However all the endpoints that follow the "www.cryptocompare.com/" pattern don't work.

I am not getting a CORS error. Just an error that says "Error: Network error" in Firefox.

Is this a problem with the API itself? Or is there something on my end I am overlooking?

Comment: Network error often means the server is down or the client has no connectivity, have you got a successful request at least one time ?

Comment: I started up the website in Chrome and checked out the error in Chrome dev tools and it says this: **Failed to load https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshotfullbyid/?id=1182: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.88**

Comment: I've gotten successful requests with any of the endpoints that start with "min-api.cryptocompare.com" but not with any that start with "www.cryptocompare.com". I'm thinking maybe they migrated the latter ones to a different endpoint and that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get(`https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD`)
```

its incorrect format I think so please retype it as

```
axios.get("https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD")
```